# building a graph from table of string records and array of keywords

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I have a table of records, each record is about a publication onm some topic, the different colums indicating the title, authors, abstract and so on

I made a function searchkeyword[string_] that searches all records that contain, either in the title or in the abstract, the specified keyword. This is a way to check what are the most popular keywors. However, keywords are not mutually exclusive, meaning that some work can contain more than 1 keyword.

To present the results to a large public, I would like to build a graph, and with that I mean something similar to this https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphData.html

I would like to have a node for each table record, and some other nodes, preferably shown as bubbles, for each keyword, and a link between a nodes'work and a blbble'node/keyword if the spoecified work contains the given keyword.

However, I have no clue how to do this, as I never used the https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphData.html function

Comment: Nah, you just want to enter a `Graph` in the form `Graph[{publication1->keyword1,publication1->keyword2,..., publication2->keyword1, publication2->keyword2, ...}]` and so on. That is one directed edge for each keyword per publication. How to get these directed edges depends very much on the way you stored the data. So nothing more can be said without a (small!) example data set.

Comment: As I said, it's stored in a table where colums are title and abstract, and keywords have to be searched inside. Like
publications={{title1, abstract1, other column without keywords},{title2, abstract2, other column without keywords}}. The way to build the association and it format is my main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a list of rules linking the publication to words and then generate a graph. e.g.

```
SeedRandom[1];
words = RandomWord["CommonWords", 10];
pub1Words = RandomSample[words, 4];
pub2Words = RandomSample[words, 5];
pub1Edges = "pub1" -> # & /@ pub1Words;
pub2Edges = "pub2" -> # & /@ pub2Words;
Graph[Join[pub1Edges, pub2Edges], VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: I understand. However, in this way you need to generate association for each publication (so maybe you can make an array for that and generate it with for or table), but maybe it's easier to make the reverse and generate association for each keyword? Keywords are like 10, publications ... many :D

Comment: My Adapted code: 
SeedRandom[1];
words = RandomWord["CommonWords", 10];
pubWords =Table[RandomSample[words, RandomInteger[1,10]],{i,1,40}];
pubEdges = Table[StringJoin["pub",ToString[i]] -> # & /@ pubWords[[i]],{i,1,40}];
Graph[Join[pubEdges], VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 500]

Comment: `RandomInteger[1,10]` should be `RandomInteger[10]` and `Join` should be `Flatten`. Also add `GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding"` for a better layout. Depending on the number of publications and words, the graph quickly becomes too hard to interpret.